# Decidability survives new constants

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory, computability-theory

Let $L$ be a finite first order language 
and let $M$ be an $L$-structure with universe $\mathbb{N}$
that interprets all $L$-symbols as recursive sets
(so $M$ is a recursive $L$-structure).

Let $L(c)$ be the extension of $L$ by a new constant symbol $c$, let
$n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $(M,n)$ be the expansion of $M$ to an 
$L(c)$-structure that interprets $c$ by $n$.

**Question:**
If $M$ is decidable, is $(M,n)$ decidable, too?

Structures are "decidable" here if the set of sentences of the resp. language that are satisfied in the structure (so, *without* naming elements of $M$) is recursive.

I assume that this is in general not the case, I even seem to remember that
Church gave a counterexample, but I cannot find it again and my memory 
might play tricks on me. I am actually looking for an answer to this question in the case when $M$ is  nearly model complete, so if somebody can comment on that case, that would be much appreciated.

**Remarks:** By basic recursion/computation theory:

1) The set of $L(c)$-consequences of the $L$-theory of $M$, is decidable.

2) If $M$ has quantifier elimination (in $L$) then the implication holds.

Comment: Remark 2 applies even if $M$ (or even $(M,n)$) is only model complete.

Comment: @Emil, I'm probably being thick, but: why does remark 2 apply if $M$ is model complete?

Comment: Any formula $\phi(x)$ is equivalent to an existential formula $\psi(x)$, and since $M$ is decidable, we can actually compute $\psi$. Then $M\models\phi(n)$ reduces to $M\models\psi(n)$, and as $\psi$ is existential and $M$ is recursive, this makes $\{\phi:M\models\phi(n)\}$ recursively enumerable. However, its complement is also recursively enumerable, as the same argument also applies to $\neg\phi(x)$. Thus, it is decidable.

Answer (score 4):

The answer appears to be negative.

**Theorem.** There is a computable graph $G$ with a decidable
theory and having a vertex $c$ for which the theory of the pointed
graph $(G,c)$ is not decidable.

Proof. Let us say that a *star* is a graph with a center node $c$
and a collection of linear rays extending out from this center
node. In other words, it is a connected tree with all vertices
having degree either one or two, except the center, which can have
higher degree. Let us refer to the linear parts of the graph
extending from the center as the *rays* of the star. Every finite
star can be viewed as coding a finite multi-set of natural
numbers, the multi-set of the lengths of its rays.

```
       /
    | /
   \|/
    c
```

Let $G_0$ be the graph consisting of countably many disjoint
copies of every possible finite star, and let $T$ be the theory of
$G_0$.

I claim, without much argument, that $T$ is a decidable theory. It seems to me that this
theory should eliminate quantifiers down to a collection of
extremely basic assertions about the nature of the stars that the
variables lie on, assertions like "$x$ is distance at most $10$
from the center of its star, distance at most 28 from the end of
its ray, and this star has 4 rays of length $25$ and $12$ but no
ray of size $16$," and "$x$ and $y$ are distance at most 5 on a
ray of the same star" and so on. If this is correct, then $T$ will
be a decidable theory. (*Update:* 
Emil has given an elegant argument in the comments showing that $T$ is 
decidable, because it is c.e. axiomatizable in a natural way and complete.)

Now, let $G$ be the graph by adding to $G_0$ an additional
infinite star, with center $c$ and rays of length $n$, for exactly
the $n$ in a fixed c.e. non-computable set $K$. A simple
compactness argument shows that this new graph still satisfies the
theory $T$, since any finite number of such assertions about rays
from $c$ are compatible with $G_0$. Furthermore, I claim that $G$
has a computable presentation. This might seem too much at first,
since $K$ is not computable, but in fact it is enough that $K$ is
merely c.e. To see why, use the odd numbers to make a computable
copy of $G_0$. With the even numbers, we use $0$ as the center of
the infinite star, and whenever $n$ is enumerated into $K$ at time
$t$, then we use the next $n$ available even numbers above $t$ as
the nodes to build the ray coming from $0$. In this way, the edge
relation becomes computable, since the nodes themselves
are big enough numbers to witness whether or not they should be
connected or not. Note that unused nodes are simply extra copies
of the star with no rays. So ultimately, we've got a computable
edge relation on $\mathbb{N}$ making a computable presentation of
the desired graph.

So we've got a computable graph $G$ of a decidable theory $T$, but
the theory of the pointed graph $(G,c)$, where $c=0$ is the center
of the newly added star, is not decidable, since the truth of
 "there is a ray of length $n$ from $c$" is equivalent to
$n\in K$, which is not decidable. QED

(Here is a link to Harizanov's Handbook article on [computable model theory](http://home.gwu.edu/~harizanv/HandbookCurrent.pdf), which contains many interesting examples and a highly developed theory.)

Comment: @Joel I mean "without parameters" and added this for clarification in the question. Thanks for the hint

Comment: I see; so in the terminology of computable model theory, what you seem to want is a computable model of a decidable theory realizing a non-computable type. 

Comment: @Joel Exactly. And the choice of the definition of "decidable model" in computable model theory indicates that there is such a type. You have a reference in mind?

Comment: I've found an example, and updated my answer. Concerning  references, the Harizanov chapter article to which I link in my answer is an excellent source for computable model theory.

Comment: Very nice! Here’s a way to prove the decidability of $T$ without explicit quantifier elimination. Let me redefine $T$ as the theory of cycle-free graphs in which no two nodes of degree $\ge3$ are connected, and which contain infinitely many copies of every finite star. It is easy to see that $T$ is recursively axiomatizable, hence it suffices to show that $T$ is complete (this will prove at once that $T$ coincides with the theory of $G_0$, that it is decidable, and that $G\equiv G_0$). I guess there are several possibilities how to show the completeness of $T$. ...

Comment: ... Here’s an argument using recursive saturation. Let $(A,B)$ be a recursively saturated pair of two countable models of $T$, it suffices to show that $A\simeq B$. It is not hard to see that if $S$ is a star in $A$ with centre $c$, there is a recursive type $\Gamma(x,c)$ expressing that $x$ (from $A$ or $B$) is the centre of a star $S'$ isomorphic to $S$: for any $n< \omega$ and $k\le\omega$, we can express by a formula (if $k$ is finite) or a set of formulas that $c$ has exactly $k$ rays of length $k$. If $c$ has finite rays of unbounded length, this already implies that $S$ and $S'$ have...

Comment: ...infinitely many infinite rays as $A$ and $B$ are individually rec.sat. If finite rays of $c$ have length bounded by $n$, then we can say that no node at distance $>n$ from the centre has degree 1, and that there are $k$ nodes at distance $n+1$, where $k$ is the number of infinite rays of $S$. Since any finite part of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable in a finite star, it follows easily that any star of $A$ or $B$ has infinitely many isomorphic copies in both $A$ and $B$. In particular, $A$ and $B$ have the same number of components of each isomorphism type, hence they are isomorphic.

Comment: Correction: “has exactly $k$ rays of length $k$” should read “... length $n$”.

Comment: Thanks, Emil, that is great! It is much easier than the quantifier-elimination argument I had had in mind. 

Comment: Quantifier elimination gives more information, though: it seems to me that it actually shows that $T$ is nearly model complete, as Marcus asked for.

Comment: I was wrong about the near model completeness. Let $\phi(x)$ be the formula “some ray of $X$ has length 1”. Let $M_0$ consist of $G_0$ and an extra star with centre $c$ and countably many rays of length 1, and construct $M_n$ from $M_0$ by extending the first $n$ rays of $c$ to length 2. Then $M_0\subseteq M_1\subseteq\dots$ and $M_\infty:=\bigcup_nM_n$ are models of $T$, and $M_n\models\phi(c)$ for every $n$, whereas $M_\infty\nvDash\phi(c)$. Thus $\phi(x)$ is not equivalent to any $\forall\exists$ formula.

Comment: What *is* true, however, is that every formula is in $T$ equivalent to a Boolean combination of existential formulas and the $\exists\forall$ formulas $\phi_{d,k,n}(x)$ saying “$x$ is at distance $d$ from the centre of a star with at least $n$ rays of length $k$”. (E.g., this follows by extension of the argument above, using the observation that if $T$ is a complete theory and $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas closed under $\land$ and $\lor$, then every formula is in $T$ equivalent to a $\Gamma$-formula iff every complete type of $T$ is axiomatizable by $\Gamma$-formulas.) ...

Comment: ... So, if we let $T'$ be the extension of $T$ by a definition of a new unary predicate $D(x)$ saying “$x$ has degree at least 2”, then $T'$ is nearly model complete (as $\phi_{d,k,n}(x)$ becomes existential), and all the other required properties continue to hold: in particular, Joel’s model is recursive even in this expanded language.

Comment: Emil, how do you say "$x$ is at distance $5$ from the terminal node of its ray" as a Boolean combination of existential formulas and the $\phi_{d,k,n}(x)$?

Comment: I don’t even need the $\phi_{d,k,n}$ here. $x$ is at distance 5 from the terminal node iff it is at distance at least 5, and it is not at distance at least 6. Now, $x$ is at distance at least $k$ iff there is a simple path of length $2k+1$ with $x$ in the middle, or for some $i=1,\dots,k$, there is a simple path with $k$ nodes on one side of $x$, and $i$ nodes on the other side, where the last of these has degree at least 3 (i.e., it is the centre of the star).

Comment: Oh, silly me, I somehow had in mind that you meant the existensial formulas would only appear positively.